# Do mobs behave differently if you have an arrow pointed at them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Many times I'll attempt to shoot a mob (such as the Enderdragon), and as soon as I've drawn back my bow the mob adopts a radically different pattern of movement, as if it's actively trying to dodge my shots.

Is this in my head or do mobs act different when you're aiming at them?

Comment: Well creepers, skeletons, zombies and spiders sure don't. They almost always run at you in a straight line, sometimes a little diagonally to avoid obstacles.

Comment: @SadlyNot Ah, I forgot to mention that in almost every case, the mob I'm aiming at has *not* noticed me (and so isn't charging at me).

Answer (score 5):

I believe the Enderdragon will attempt to dodge arrows. Also, Endermen cannot be shot by arrows because they teleport right before being hit. I believe the other mobs moving when an arrow is pointed at them is either coincidental or a small glitch.

Comment: Skeletons and creepers strafe (to the right; the player's left) when they're close to you. It does make them harder to aim at, but it's not in reaction to anything you're doing, just their normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have studied the Minecraft code lots, and by nature the Endermen are programmed to dodge arrows. 
Best of luck,

Answer (score 0):

No, the mobs won't act differently but when fired at an enderman the enderman will teleport away right before the arrow hits. The Ender dragon will not try to dodge arrows if he is coming to attack you so that is usually the best way to kill it if you have an enchanted bow. None aggressive mobs will look at you though if you aim a bow at them almost pleadingly not to shoot them. It's actually very sad.

Comment: Passive mobs will look at you for a few seconds when you look at them, bow or no bow.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I battled the ender dragon, but back when I did, I would hold the bow drawn for a long time, until he was right in front of me.  Shoot, then he'd peel off, and try to escape my next shot.  That's probably a 1.2 story.

Comment: Hitting the Ender dragon makes it change direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ender Dragons are one of the two boss mobs implemented into Minecraft, and it's designed to have more complicated AI. That means it probably can dodge arrows, but the only way to confirm this is to hack the game. Regular mobs such as zombies and skeletons certainly don't dodge arrows, the only exception to this is Endermen, which teleport away from any projectiles, including splash potions, thrown at them.